# Thread methods call without Thread instance

Tags: java, multithreading

Why this class is compiling without errors on line 11, and how interpret the last line of output :

```
class Bang extends Thread {

    static Thread t1;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("main thread ID = " + Thread.currentThread().getId());
        t1 = new Thread(new Bang());
        t1.setPriority(7);
        t1.setName("T1");
        t1.start();
    }

    public void run() {
        Thread th = Thread.currentThread();
        System.out.println(th.getId() + " " + th.getName() + "        "
                + th.getPriority() + "  " + th.toString() + "\n");
        System.out.println(getId() + " " + getName() + "  " + getPriority()
                + "  " + toString());
    }
}
```

Output :

main thread ID = 1
9 T1        7  Thread[T1,7,main]

8 Thread-0  5  Thread[Thread-0,5,main]

Thanks,

Comment: Because `extends Thread`.

Comment: What error were you expecting?

Comment: In line System.out.println(getId + ....);, because instance method a called whithout an instance or if is an implicit one what is ?What thread has id = 8 ? Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

@Tunaki is spot on. I'll just add to what he said.

There are three Thread objects totally.

1. Main Thread object which is a java.lang.Thread
2. T1 thread object which is a java.lang.Thread
3. Bang thread object which is a Bang

Note that, the Main thread and the T1 thread are ***spawned*** as separate threads, whereas Bang thread is ***not spawned***.

What you print inside the `run` method is running on the thread T1.

`Thread.currentThread().getId()` will return the id of the running thread ***T1*** which is **9**.

`this.getId()` will return the id of the ***Bang*** object which is **8**. Remember, you created Bang object before the T1 object? That's why Bang has a lesser id **8**, and T1 has a higher threadId of **9**.

Hope this helps. I have updated your code to print more info about hashcode and class details. The output should give a clear picture.

## Code:

```
class Bang extends Thread {

    static Thread t1;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("main thread ID = " + Thread.currentThread().getId());
        Bang bang = new Bang(); //Creating a local variable so we can print the object details.
        t1 = new Thread(bang);
        t1.setPriority(7);
        t1.setName("T1");
        threadInfo(bang);
        threadInfo(t1);
        t1.start();
    }
    public void run() {
        threadInfo(this);
    }
    public static void threadInfo(Thread argThreadObject) {
        System.out.println("===================================");
        Thread currentThreadObject = Thread.currentThread();
        printThreadInfo("currentThreadObject", currentThreadObject);
        printThreadInfo("argThreadObject", argThreadObject);
        System.out.println("===================================");
    }
    public static void printThreadInfo(String threadObjId, Thread threadObject) {
        System.out.println(
                threadObjId + ": " 
                + threadObject.getId() + ":"
                + threadObject.getName() + ":" 
                + threadObject.getPriority() + ":" 
                + threadObject.toString() + " instanceId: "
                + threadObject.hashCode() + "@"
                + threadObject.getClass().getName());
    }
}
```

## Output

```
main thread ID = 1
===================================
currentThreadObject: 1:main:5:Thread[main,5,main] instanceId: 1113847530@java.lang.Thread
argThreadObject: 9:T1:7:Thread[T1,7,main] instanceId: 820485811@java.lang.Thread
===================================
===================================
currentThreadObject: 1:main:5:Thread[main,5,main] instanceId: 1113847530@java.lang.Thread
argThreadObject: 8:Thread-0:5:Thread[Thread-0,5,main] instanceId: 912528090@Bang
===================================
===================================
currentThreadObject: 9:T1:7:Thread[T1,7,main] instanceId: 820485811@java.lang.Thread
argThreadObject: 8:Thread-0:5:Thread[Thread-0,5,main] instanceId: 912528090@Bang
===================================
```

Comment: Excellent ! Thank you very much !

Comment: If this answered your question thoroughly, you can accept this answer.